# Regexextract of importdata from website GoogleSheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The purpose is to extract the [title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW7sL.png) and [tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecuoe.png) from a [webpage](https://www.etsy.com/listing/664521415/svg-bundle-all-files-in-shop-svg-bundle?ref=shop_home_active_1&crt=1).

I'm using `importdata` and I want to have the results all in 1 row. Like this:

```
[webpage] [title] [1st tag] [2nd tag] [3 rd tag] [4th tag] ... [last tag]
```

---

I am stuck halfway [my process in googlesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RlEFR_QVosdvWCRfI7rogtAlvleOWzFt9Filhl5UKc/edit?usp=sharing)

- first tab `Extracted`  - I've extracted the necessary lines from the
  big data.

  ```
  =query({array_constrain(IMPORTDATA(A1),6375,10)},"WHERE (Col1 CONTAINS 'btn btn-secondary' AND Col1 CONTAINS 'href') or (Col1 CONTAINS 'meta property' AND Col1 CONTAINS 'og:title')")
  ```
- second tab `with REGEXEXTRACT` - extracted the text I need, but only works for the first line (only extracted `tags`, `title` still not there as it spreads across a few columns...)

  ```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(query({array_constrain(IMPORTDATA(A1),6375,10)},"WHERE (Col1 CONTAINS 'btn btn-secondary' AND Col1 CONTAINS 'href')"),"\>(.+)\
  ```

I don't know how to go further :( Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello, formulas are in the `my process in spreadsheet`
I just copied them to the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,
 QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTDATA(A2),"""",""),1000,15),
 "where Col1 contains '<meta property=og:title content='")),
 "<meta property=og:title content=| />",""),
 TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTDATA(A2),"""",""),8000,3)),,50000)),
 "where Col1 contains '<a class=btn btn-secondary'"),"\>(.*)+\<"))})
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFKgg533N_L_Ef3IjAYtzJoDix9tqYhPboXHoF53YVo/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Hello! 
**1)** After `query`, [Disney Svg Bundle] and [Monogram" />] are missing for title
  
**2)** It doesnt work on this [link](https://www.etsy.com/listing/681820931/bunnies-are-awesome-t-shirt-cute-rabbit) (this is also an Etsy product link)
@player0